# creating the ipa some questions

Tags: xcode

I know its been asked many times , and i have read , but there are things that i cant connect to each other here .

I have to create .ipa to send to other developer to run on HIS device .

So i have to "write" his device UDID .and so the questions are:

1. Do i have to add a new device to the provisioning profile on the dev center,create a developing provisioning and drag it again to xcode -to have the new device in my project ??
2. Do i need also the distribution provisioning with the new device for that ?
3. What code signing do i need to set for it ?
4. Exact steps to .ipa with the latest xcode version would be great .

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple Documentation: Beta Testing Your iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1)

[This Youtube Video is covering your all questions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAdV16nRLp8)